# Almost covergence and bounded in norm implies integerable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to prove the following proposition:

---

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1(\Omega)$ such that

(1)$f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x) \text { a.e. }$

(2)$\left(f_{n}\right) \text { is bounded in } L^{1}(\Omega) \text { i.e., }\left\|f_{n}\right\|_{1} \leq M \quad \forall n$

then $f\in L^1(\Omega)$.

---

It looks like an easy problem but I failed many times. I can prove the proposition if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly or in norm or in measure. However I don't see how to prove this if $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int|f|=\int\lim_{n}|f_{n}|\leq\liminf_{n}\int|f_{n}|\leq M<\infty.
\end{align*}